# Doxygen link to const function

Tags: c++, constants, doxygen

I've got the following function prototype:

```
bool key_pressed(enum key key) const;
```

I documented it using doxygen. Now I have an overloaded version of that function that does the same, so I wanted to copy the doxygen comment like this:

```
/// @copydoc key_pressed(enum key) const
bool key_pressed(char key) const;
```

This does not work, I get the following warning from doxygen:

```
Warning: target key_pressed(enum key) const of \copydoc command not found
```

If I remove the *const* from key_pressed(enum key) and from the @copydoc line, it works.

Did I specify the modifier correctly in my copydoc command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/// @copydoc key_pressed(enum key) const
```

Should this not be `(enum key key)`? Not that I would advise using the same name for the input parameter as the enum name...

Comment: That does the trick! Weird, because the Doxygen documentation states that parameter names can be omitted for autolinking! About naming it the same - I can't really come up with useful alternatives. Avoiding this is the one big benefit of camel notation IMO.